# Retrieve description from a pull request

Tags: github, github-cli

Ive been reading github cli but could not find how to do it or did just miss it.How do you retrieve the body from a comment in a pull request?

[comment description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQsin.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gh pr view 3 --repo JoeffreyChaucer/test-cherry-pick
```